# How to get list[[i,j]] from a list {i,j}

Tags: list-manipulation

My problem is more complicated than what follows but this is the minimal working example.

Lets say I have:

```
l1={1,2}
```

I have a list:

```
list={{{0,0}},{{1,1}},{{2,2}},{{3,3}}}
```

I want to access list[[1,2]] but using l1, thus I need to convert the list into parameters to give to Part.

I tried the following but it doesn't work and I am not sure to understand why:

```
Part[list, #] & @@ l1
```

How can I proceed ? I know that I could do: list[[l1[[1]],l1[[2]]] but in addition to be dirty, imagine a problem with many more list depth/size and it wouldnt be a good answer.

Comment: The part `list[[1, 2]]` does not exist in your example. However, what you're looking for is `Part[list, ##]& @@ l1` or `list[[Sequence @@ l1]]`. Or you can use `Extract[list, l1]` instead.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit indeed I didn't exactly copied my example I made a mistake but you got my point. Hoo great for Sequence I didn't know that function it looks super usefull. Thanks